# como fazer um select count utilizando Linq C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, linq

preciso converter este trecho de código SQL para Linq C#. Eu já consegui converter praticamente todo código.

```
SELECT COUNT(Q.ID_QUALIFICACAO) AS CONHEC_ESPECIFICO 
                        FROM QUALIFICACAO Q 
                        INNER JOIN 
                            ATENDIMENTO A ON Q.ID_QUALIFICACAO = A.ID_QUALIFICACAO AND 
                            Q.NOTACONHECESPECIF IN (9,10) AND 
                            A.ID_TERAPEUTA = 0 AND 
                            A.ATENDIMENTOREALIZADO = 1
```

Com excessão da linha **Q.NOTACONHECESPECIF IN (9,10)**

A coluna NOTACONHECESPECIF é do tipo inteiro e não consigo aplicar a função **Contains** para ela.

O que consegui produzir até agora está baixo:

```
 var numero = (from q in db.QUALIFICACAOs
                              join a in db.ATENDIMENTOes on q.ID_QUALIFICACAO equals a.ID_QUALIFICACAO
                              where  (q.NOTACONHECESPECIF == 10 || q.NOTACONHECESPECIF == 9) &&
                                     a.ID_TERAPEUTA == ID_TERAPEUTA &&
                                     a.ATENDIMENTOREALIZADO == true
                                     select new
                                          {
                                            q.NOTACONHECESPECIF
                                          }).Count();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça um array com os valores inteiros:

```
var arraynota = new int[] { 9, 10};

var arraynota = (from q in db.QUALIFICACAOs
                              join a in db.ATENDIMENTOes on q.ID_QUALIFICACAO equals a.ID_QUALIFICACAO
                              where  (q.NOTACONHECESPECIF in arraynota) &&
                                     a.ID_TERAPEUTA == ID_TERAPEUTA &&
                                     a.ATENDIMENTOREALIZADO == true
                                     select new
                                          {
                                            q.NOTACONHECESPECIF
                                          }).Count();
```

Acredito que isso irá lhe atender.